# GAS1列×2をしようとしているがうまくいかない

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS初心者で、以下×2をしようとしているのですが、うまくいかないです。なんでしょう。
よろしくお願いします。

以下

```
function moto2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origin = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('元2');
  var origin_last_row = origin.getLastRow();
  var origin_last_col = origin.getLastColumn();
  origin.getRange(2, 1, origin_last_row-1, origin_last_col).sort([{column: 1, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: true},{column:14, ascending: false}]);
  var kake = origin.getRange(i, 15)
  for (var i=2; i<=11; i++) {
    origin.getRange(i, 15).setValue(kake * 2);
 }
}
```

```
メソッド getRange((class),number) が見つかりません。（行 7、ファイル「元2」
```

Comment: `var kake = origin.getRange(i, 15)` の部分の `i` が未定義だからです。

Comment: iを定義してもうまく2倍ならないのは、そもそも構文間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、、for loop の内部に `var kake = origin.getRange(i, 15).getValue()` を置くと良いかと。

Comment: 有難うございました。